# How do I install a ceiling fan without creating holes in the ceiling?

Tags: electrical, ceiling, ceiling-fan

I wanted to install ceiling fans in my house but there there were no existing outlets in the ceiling so I got an electrician to do it. He created 2 holes in the ceiling and 2 in the wall to run the wire through. These holes look ugly and they need lot of work to cover them up. I dont want to do the same thing in my master bedroom.

Is there any other way I can install a ceiling fan without digging holes in the ceiling or wall and still get the wires run inside the walls?

Comment: Why not just use those decorative hanging hooks with the wire in a chain to run the ceiling fan to an outlet? People have been doing that for years.

Comment: Hanging a ceiling fan from a decorative hook sounds like a pretty major safety issue.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Repairing the holes in your walls doesn't need to be such a daunting task.  Have a quick look at this video on how to patch your drywall:

[This Old House - Drywall 101](http://www.thisoldhouse.com/toh/video/0,,20052318,00.html)

It will look far better in the long run if you let the wiring be run within the walls and learn how to patch them.  All told the drywall (you can often get small 2x2 boards for patch work at Home Depot), cutting knife, spreaders, joint compound (premixed)and tape will run you around $50.  By contrast running electrical in conduit will cost you just that much for the conduit alone and look far less appealing.

Comment: Great video tutorial. I wish i can upvote this 10 times :)

Answer (score 5):

Unless you can get access to the ceiling from above then it will be difficult to run the wiring without creating extra holes.

If there is a room above the master bedroom you should be able to lift floorboards to gain access - however that can cause more problems as, if you have tongue and groove boards, you need to break at least one board to get the rest up. If there is  loft space above the bedroom you could gain access that way, but you'll need to move insulation out of the way first and then ensure it's relaid correctly.

I would get quotes from different electricians and explicitly mention that you want the minimum disruption to the walls and ceiling and that they have to make good any extra holes they create in the process.

Comment: I have attic above master bedroom. I better get someone to check if one hole for the box will do there. Thanks for the advice.